# PHP Session not working correctly on a particular host

Tags: php, session, hosting

I have this script that works well on other servers but the session part fails on a particular host. I have pointed to another server but would really like to figure out what could be the problem. I have observed that :

1. It takes 5-15 mins for changes on code to reflect(e.g changing
   text on index page).The server seems to cache pages especially index
   (BTW i cleared my browsers cache e.t.c)
2. When i logout and login as another user the server still retains
   the session of the last user on the index page (the other pages seem
   OK)
3. I can open index.php (without logging any user) and what i
   believe is the last logged in users details display

I tried swapping my code for some authentication systems on github (just to be sure) even PHPAuth which uses cookies (not sessions) fails the same way. But the same code works flawlessly on localhost as well as other servers.

So i would like to figure out exactly what goes on on that host. It is a shared hosting package.

Comment: Why don't you ask the host? We don't even know what host it is so I'm not sure how you expect us to tell you anything about it.

Comment: I've sent them a message will be waiting for their reply, but i was really curious if anyone has experienced something similar, it seemed really odd to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a reply from the host. Seems the problem was with the hosts session variable path. They fixed it.Thanks